# Approximate the probability that the stock’s price will be up at least 30 percent after the next 1000 periods

Tags: probability

A model for the movement of a stock supposes that if the present price of the stock is s, then, after one period, it will be either us with probability p or ds with probability 1 − p.

Assuming that successivemovements are independent, approximate the probability that the stock’s price will be up at least 30 percent after the next 1000 periods if u = 1.012, 
d = 0.990, and p = .52.

Thanks for everything :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the stock start at $1$ dollar. Let $S_i=u$ with probability $p$, and let $S_i=d$ with probability $1-p$. Then the stock price after $n$ periods is the random variable $X$, where
$$X=S_1S_2S_3\cdots S_n.$$
Let $Y=\ln X$. Then 
$$Y=\ln S_1+\ln S_2+\ln S_3+\cdots+\ln S_n.$$
We want the probability that $X\ge 1.30$, that is, that $Y\ge \ln(1.30)$.

The $\ln S_i$ are independent identically distributed random variables. Since we are letting $n$ be large ($1000$), we can assume that the distribution of $Y$ is nearly normal. So if we can find the mean and variance of $Y$, the rest will be a standard normal calculation.

We need the mean and variance of the $\ln S_i$. The mean of $\ln S_i$ is straightforward, since $S_i=u$ with probability $p$, and $S_i=d$ with probability $1-p$. Thus $E(\ln S_i)=p\ln u+(1-p)\ln d$. It follows that $E(Y)=n(p\ln u+(1-p)\ln d)$.

For the variance of the $\ln S_i$, we need $E((\ln S_i)^2)-(E(\ln S_i))^2$. 
We already know one of the components. For the other, note that
$E((\ln S_i)^2)=p(\ln u)^2+(1-p)(\ln d)^2$. For the variance of $Y$, since the $\ln S_i$ are independent, just multiply by $n$.

The rest is calculator work.

**Another way:** We wanted to show the power of the sum/product of random variables approach, but there is a quicker way. This time we work numerically. Suppose there are $k$ "up" days and therefore $1000-k$ down days. Then our stock price rises from $1$ to $(1.012)^k (0.990)^{1000-k}$. We want this to be $\ge 1.30$.
Let us see where we have equality. So we are solving 
$$\left(\frac{1.012}{0.990}\right)^k (0.990)^{1000}=1.30.$$
Do some algebra, using logarithms. We get
$$k(\ln(1.012)-\ln(0.990)=\ln(1.30)-1000\ln(0.990).$$
I get something like $k=469.2$. So if the number of up days is $469.2$ or greater, we will have gone up by $30\%$ or more. We want the probability that a binomial random variable, $n=1000$, $p=0.52$, is greater than $469.2$. To do the calculation, use the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: Thanks for your help, always help me :D, have a nice day

Comment: You are welcome. I have left the numerical calculations to you. They are not particularly painful. May add a "quickie" approach, next $10$ minutes.

Comment: Perfect answer :o :o , I understood very well, thanks for your time and your patience 

Have a excellent day